# Deleting markers automaticaly created by Google directionsService

Tags: javascript, google-api-javascript-client

How can I delete all markers created by directionsService when using:

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer)

The example I´m working with is Waypoints in Directions se link bellow:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for Minimal, Reproducible Example for getting better answers from community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is solved not by deleting the markers, but making then invisible worked well, then I could go on and create own cool markers.